# small python code refactor

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having this piece of code, which in my opinion is fairly ugly and I am wondering how it can be done better:

```
if dic.get(key, None) is None:
   dic[key] = None
```

Points for elegance ;-)

Answer (score 10):

```
d.setdefault(key) # sets d[key] to None if key is not in d
```

Comment: you don't need to have `None` there explicitly, `default` argument defaults to `None`

Comment: @SilentGhost: hehe, I realised that and changed my answer precisely at the same time as you were writing the comment. :-)

Comment: This is *considerably* faster than any other method, as it implements the check in C and thus avoids all the temporary reference counting.

Answer (score 7):

```
if key not in dic:
    dic[key] = None
```

This might not be as short as Olivier's code, but at least it's explicit and fast.

Please, don't use `dict` as a variable name, it shadows built-in.

Answer (score 3):

```
import collections

mydict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)
```

Now, any access to `mydict[akey]` will (if `akey` was not present as a key in `mydict`) set `mydict[akey]` to `None` as a side effect.

Note that `defaultdict`'s initializer requires a no-arguments callable, whence the `lambda`.